# About the finite generation of log canonical rings in BCHM

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $(X,B)$ be a klt pair where $K_X+B$ is $\mathbb{R}$-Cartier. Let $\pi:X\rightarrow U$ be a projective morphism of quasi-projective varieties. Assume either that $B$ is $\pi$-big and $K_X+B$ is $\pi$-pseudo-effective, or $K_X+B$ is $\pi$-big, then the work of Birkar-Cascini-Hacon-McKernan proves that the log canonical ring
$$\mathfrak{R}(\pi,K_X+B)=\bigoplus_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\pi_*\mathcal{O}_X(\left\lfloor m(K_X+B)\right\rfloor )$$
is a finitely generated $\mathcal{O}_U$-algebra under the assumption that $K_X+B$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier.

I wonder why can't we derive the same conclusion when $K_X+B$ is just $\mathbb{R}$-Cartier? After all, the coefficients of $B$ should cause no trouble after being rounded down, and $\mathfrak{R}(\pi,K_X+B)$ should be the same as when $K_X+B$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier. What am I missing?

Comment: If you don’t get an answer here for a while, it might be worth trying at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net) (of course indicating the cross-post). This seems like a research-level question to me – I’ve never heard of most of the terms used.

Comment: @joriki Thanks for the heads-up

Comment: Are you asking why the $\mathbb{R}$-Cartier case doesn't follow from the $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier case, or more why the $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier assumption is necessary for the proof?

Comment: @Daniel Sorry for the confusion, The latter is my question. Specifically, why the finite generation fails when the coefficients of the boundary divisor are irrational.